# Picture/Video capture programs

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

What software options are there for taking videos and or pictures within Ubuntu (Much like Apple's Photobooth)?

*Please limit one software solution per answer and include key features/description of the software*

Comment: This has been made more generic from the original posters question of "Alternatives for Cheese" in order to make it work better on this site. While Cheese will inevitably be an answer to this question, so will every other available software *like* cheese making it not only work for the Original Poster, but also everyone else (Those looking Alternatives to either Cheese - or software similar to Cheese).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [cheese](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cheese) [image: Install cheese]

Cheese uses your webcam to take photos and videos, applies fancy special effects and lets you share the fun with others.

Cheese uses GStreamer to apply fancy effects to photos and videos. With Cheese it is easy to take photos of you, your friends, pets or whatever you want and share them with others. After the success of the Summer of Code, the development continued and we still are looking for people with nice ideas and patches ;)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to increase FPS on cheese. I get sluggish videos and while taking pics I have to stay still for about 2 sec for the picture to be stabalized.

Answer (score 7):

## [Camorama Webcam Viewer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/camorama) [image: Install Camorama]

```
sudo apt-get install camorama
```

[image: Caomorana screenshot]

Comment: Good option to do basic capturing and adjustments. Required only 1 package (camorama - ~1MB post install) as opposed to 33 packages (~79MB) required for cheese on my setup.

Answer (score 4):

## [GTK+ base UVC Viewer [image: Install UVC Viewer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guvcview/)

It has a clean, intuitive design that makes it very easy to use, and gives excellent results each time.

[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

QtCAM is a free, Open Source Linux Webcamera Software with more than 10 image control settings, extension settings and Color space switching.

[image: Still capture settings in QtCAM]