# Time and date inside a video capture

Tags: software-recommendation, video, capture

Which video capture programs exists with this option: time and date displayed inside the video? I checked [these programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9775/picture-video-capture-programs/307720#307720), but I didn't find nothing in this sense.

Comment: check this question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/428500/how-to-add-time-stamp-when-using-ffmpeg-webcan-recording/428501#428501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Kino](http://www.kinodv.org). In [this](http://www.kinodv.org/dcforum?az=printer_friendly&forum=101&topic_id=2491) link they mention your same problem.
TL;DR: Go to view -> FX -> Filter -> Titler. Then you could use:

#timecode#

#dv.timecode#

#dv.datetime#

Answer (score 2):

First Install ffmpeg :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Second To activate Time Stamp use this command which will start recording your web-cam and add to it time-stamp , and it will save your recording as .mp4 file in the directory you are running your command .

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -r 30 -vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='\%T': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k \
-preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

[image]

Sorry i put my Finger on my cam :D

Enjoy your Time !

Reference : [Add Time Stamp in ffmpeg](http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/)

Answer (score -1):

After trying several times , I have finally found a command that creates a video displaying current Date Time ( text='%{localtime:%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S}' )

From the command line using avconv:

```
avconv -nostats -loglevel 0 -t 3595 -i /dev/video0 -s hd1080 -vf \ 
drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='%{localtime\:%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S}' : fontcolor=yellow@0.8: x=7: y=460"  \
/home/pi/c615/vf/c615_$now.avi
```

Edit the input file (after -i), output file (last line) and fonts to suit your needs.