# Software to use webcam as camera

Tags: webcam, camera

Is there software that allows the webcam to be used as a camera?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: Aand just what is the distinction between the two?

Comment: What's the difference? With the help of a video capture card I use my Camera as Webcam through analog CVBS input. Some troubles with deinterlacing (as webcam) but works.

Comment: @YatharthROCK I want to use my webcam as a camera to take some pics of objects on my desk.

Comment: A webcam is, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcam) meant to be used via a computer. You can just use any regular camera application (the most popular being Cheese) to get the stream then.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As your goal is to take pictures of your desk, I'd suggest to install `cheese`

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

Then start it with just `cheese` from the same terminal or from the Dash:

[image]

Comment: @itsols Let me get this straight: you were simply looking for recommendations for picture/video capture software? Did you search AskUbuntu first? A quick glance turns up http://askubuntu.com/questions/9775/picture-video-capture-programs and others...

Comment: I did not know that I had to look for picture or video editing/capturing software. I just wanted to get my webcam working as a camera. Thanks for the link anyway!

Answer (score 8):

Another nice alternative to cheese: **GTK UCV Video Viewer**

Install it using `sudo apt-get install guvcview`

Answer (score 2):

May I assume you wish to be able to take a still photo with your webcam? If so, I recommend *cheese*. It is available in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

After you start it, there is an option to take a photo, photos in a burst or videos.